# Saving menu state CSS - Accordian Menu - no Jquery

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I have an accordian menu which is common to all pages. When a user clicks on a submenu it will take the user to that link but since a whole new page loads, the menu has collapsed back.

Is there a way of saving the menu state using Vanilla Javascript? I have seen solutions using Jquery which is not in use.

I have the snippet of my menu below for reference.

```css
.nav_bar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.nav_bar .nav_header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_bar .nav_header .nav_logo {
  width: 180px;
}

.nav_bar .menu {
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item .sub_menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item .sub_menu a::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  background: #280F98;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item .sub_menu a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item:target .sub_menu {
  max-height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_bar">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" id="our_work">
            <a href="#our_work" class="button">Our Work</a>
            <div class="sub_menu">
                <a href="our_work">Our mission</a>
                <a href="our_work#goals">Goals</a>
                <a href="our_work#initiatives">Initiatives</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="performances">
            <a href="#performances" class="button">Showcase</a>
            <div class="sub_menu">
                <a href="#">2020</a>
                <a href="#">2019</a>
                <a href="#">2018</a>
                <a href="#">2017</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="concerts">
            <a href="#concerts" class="button">Talent</a>
            <div class="sub_menu">
                <a href="#">Concerts 1</a>
                <a href="#">Concerts 2</a>
                <a href="#">Concerts 3</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="shop">
            <a href="#shop" class="button">Shop</a>
            <div class="sub_menu">
                <a href="#">Shop 1</a>
                <a href="#">Shop 2</a>
                <a href="#">Shop 3</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: A possible answere is adding a javascript DOM line: `document.querySelector("." + current + " .sub_menu").style.maxHeight = '10em';` But this is hard coding the menu to be open. Now the menu won't close when other menu's are opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I added `SO TEST` menu item with `href: js` as that is snippet location link as seen in console log.

Menu opening is based on `a href` link and current location.

**EDIT:**

As requested in comment, added click event on all main menu categories. If one is clicked, it will first hide all sub menus (in order to hide if any is previously shown) then show only clicked sub menus items.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const page = location.href.split("/").pop();

  console.log(location.href);
  console.log(page);

  [...document.querySelectorAll(".nav_bar > .menu > .item > .sub_menu a")].forEach(link => {
    if (link.href.endsWith(page)) {
      link.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
      link.parentElement.setAttribute("style", "max-height: 10em");
    }
  })
})

const menus = document.querySelectorAll(".nav_bar > .menu > .item ")
for (const menu of menus) {
  menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    [...document.querySelectorAll(".nav_bar > .menu > .item > .sub_menu a")].forEach(link => {
      link.parentElement.setAttribute("style", "max-height: 0em");
    })
    this.getElementsByClassName("sub_menu")[0].setAttribute("style", "max-height: 10em");
  })
}
```

```css
.nav_bar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.nav_bar .nav_header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav_bar .nav_header .nav_logo {
  width: 180px;
}

.nav_bar .menu {
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item .sub_menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item .sub_menu a::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  background: #280F98;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item .sub_menu a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_bar .menu .item:target .sub_menu {
  max-height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_bar">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" id="our_work">
      <a href="#our_work" class="button">Our Work</a>
      <div class="sub_menu">
        <a href="js">SO TEST</a>
        <a href="our_work">Our mission</a>
        <a href="our_work#goals">Goals</a>
        <a href="our_work#initiatives">Initiatives</a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="performances">
      <a href="#performances" class="button">Showcase</a>
      <div class="sub_menu">
        <a href="#">2020</a>
        <a href="#">2019</a>
        <a href="#">2018</a>
        <a href="#">2017</a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="concerts">
      <a href="#concerts" class="button">Talent</a>
      <div class="sub_menu">
        <a href="#">Concerts 1</a>
        <a href="#">Concerts 2</a>
        <a href="#">Concerts 3</a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="shop">
      <a href="#shop" class="button">Shop</a>
      <div class="sub_menu">
        <a href="#">Shop 1</a>
        <a href="#">Shop 2</a>
        <a href="#">Shop 3</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. Some neat little tricks in your js that I never thought of. Just a quick one. Is there a way of making the menu close when the user clicks on other menus. My guess is that since we are setting the code in JS it gets precedent and stands above the other css code so the menu stays open.

Comment: Fantastic. You I was down the same path improvising your code albeit with much uglier coding. To make it neater I removed the `load` listener and added a flat `document.getElementById(page).getElementsByClassName("sub_menu")[0].style.maxHeight = '10em';` where `page` is where i fetch class name through URL like you did. It works. Thanks.

Comment: @amars That could work, But my version seems safer, it does not depend on that you have to give ids and hrefs same value. But yeah sure, it can work that way.